# SheetJS library treats text as date incorrectly

Tags: javascript, csv, export-to-excel, sheetjs

There is a CSV file, which I try to read and it contains field with value

```
"Aprobil P 0.1%"
```

the short example of CSV:

```
"Country";"Product Family"
"Germany";"Aprobil P 0.1%"
```

conversion to workbook is the following:

```
var workbook = XLSX.read(csvData, {
                    type:'string',
                    dateNF: 'D-M-YYYY',
                    cellDates:true,
                    cellText:true,
                    cellNF: false,
                raw:false});
```

after conversion I save the XLS, where value **"Aprobil P 0.1%"** is converted to a date **01.04.00**

Looking into the worksheet model and getting the certain cell, it contains:

```
{
      t: 'd',
      v: 'Sat Apr 01 2000 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)',
      z:undefined
}
```

The best way I see at the moment is to set the **raw** to **true** and
 process the values in my own way.
Or 2) replace all occurrences of Aprobil to something similar, but looks like I need to to the same trick for all the 12 months...

Is there any other way to cover this case?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
read options : {cellText:false,cellDates:true}
```

In your conversion function:

```
var data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(ws, {header:1, raw:false, dateNF:'D-M-YYYY'});
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found that cellDates is rounding some values: [Issue](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/issues/1212)

It happens in some scenarios when the **raw flag is disabled**. As a workaround, I converted another JSON and **compared It with the original one**, changing the date on the format that I want.

```
let jsonByPage = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheetName],{header:"A", raw:false });
    jsonByPage = cleanDates(buf,jsonByPage,sheetName,"YYYY-MM-DD");
```

Here is the cleanDates method:

```
cleanDates(buf,oldJSONByPage,sheetName, format){
      //Get the data with dates and parsing the other values like Strings,Integers.
      let newWoorkbook = XLSX.read(buf,{ cellNF:false,cellText:false, cellDates:true});
      let jsonByPage = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(newWoorkbook.Sheets[sheetName],{header:"A", raw:true });
      //Loop the sheet
      for(const index of jsonByPage.keys()) {
        let rowWithDate = jsonByPage[index];
        //Iterate the row
        for (const key in rowWithDate)
        {
          let value =rowWithDate[key];
          if (value instanceof Date)
          {
            oldJSONByPage[index][key] = moment(value).format(format);
          }
        };
      }
      return oldJSONByPage;
    }
```

Best regards.